# Gerando datas , a partir de uma data digitada e quantidade mês informado

Tags: java

Tenho que gerar uma data automática a partir da data e quantidade de mês informado.

```
      Ex:Data digitada: 01/04/2014, Quantidade mês: 5 meses.
```

Toda vez que o acabar o ano, ele muda para o próximo automático.

Comment: Olá Wellson, você poderia explicar melhor o que você precisa e o que você já tentou?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833399/changing-java-date-one-hour-back

Comment: Assim tenho o campo onde eu digito a data (19/11/2014) e outro campo onde eu digito a  quantidade  de mês,  tipo 5 mês ou 24 meses. Levando em conta se colocamos 5 meses Ai ele vai somar 5 meses a partir da data que eu digitei, ai quando for janeiro ele muda o ano automático.

Comment: Para o Java 7 ou inferior veja o link do @Guilherme sobre a classe `Calendar`. Para o Java 8 você pode usar uma `LocalDate` e o método [plusMonths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusMonths-long-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O OP encontrou uma solução sozinho.

Mesmo assim, por referência, segue como eu faria isso no Java 8 com a [Date and Time API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310):

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

// ...

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
String comecoCurso = "19/11/2014";
int duracaoCurso = 5;
//  Na vida real faca algo com excecoes como DateTimeParseException e DateTimeException
LocalDate terminoCurso = LocalDate.parse(comecoCurso, formatter).plusMonths(duracaoCurso);
System.out.print(terminoCurso.format(formatter));
```

E a versão para Java 7 ou inferior:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 

// ...

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String comecoCurso = "19/11/2014";
int duracaoCurso = 5;
try {
    Date dataInicial = formatter.parse(comecoCurso);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(dataInicial);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, duracaoCurso);
    Date dataTermino = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println(formatter.format(dataTermino));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // trate essa e outras excecoes
}
```

Comment: Muito interessante essa  forma ai !

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVI DESSA FORMA]

```
    String data_f = "";
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    String data = "19/11/2014";
    Integer duracaoCurso = 5;

    Integer ano = Integer.valueOf(data.substring(6, 10));



    Date datadig = formatarData(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < duracaoCurso; i++) {
        gc.setTime(datadig);
        gc.add(Calendar.MONTH, duracaoCurso);

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        java.util.Date d = (java.util.Date) gc.getTime();

        if (ano == gc.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {

            gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, gc.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
        } else {
            gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, gc.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        }


        if (i == duracaoCurso - 1) {
            data_f = df.format(d);

        }

    }

    System.out.println(data_f);
}

private static Date formatarData(String data) throws ParseException, Exception {
    String temp = data;
    temp = temp.replace("/", "").trim();
    if (temp == null || temp.trim().isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception("Data  em branco - Por favor verifique a data digitada!");
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return new Date(formatter.parse(data).getTime());
    }
}
```

Saida 19/04/2015 , adicionado 5 meses a data ;